# Substring right after another substring

Tags: php, string, function

So I have this big string, which includes in the middle the following:

```
"(...) Status: Ativo
Identificador: F36CE5
Meio de Pagamento: Cartão de crédito
Data de contratação: 25/03/2015
Data de expiração: 25/03/2017 (...)"
```

`* the "(...)" is just to identify that there are more content before and after this part`

My goal is to isolate only the part right after `"Identificador:"`, i.e., I need to grab the value `"F36CE5"` (which is different every time, of course) and set it to a variable.

I tried the following code:

```
$initialString = "Status: Ativo
Identificador: F37CE5
Meio de Pagamento: Cartão de crédito
Data de contratação: 25/03/2015
Data de expiração: 25/03/2017";


$arr = explode(":", $initialString);
$important = $arr[2];
echo $important;
```

But with this I am getting

```
F37CE5
Meio de Pagamento
```

What should I do to get only `F37CE5`?

Is there a way to tell PHP: "Give the string that is right after 'Identificador:', and nothing more" ?

Comment: use `preg_*` functions family, like `preg_match` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression.
Something like:

```
<?php
$pattern = '/Identificador: (\w+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $initialString, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

$matches[1] will contain the string you are looking for.

Comment: It's called a regular expression, this pattern is used to try and match a substring inside a string. In this case, it matches any "word character" (\w) after "Identificador: ". The plus (+) sign means to match 1 or more of the preceding token (the \w part). Without the plus sign it would just match the first character, which is "F". Look up regular expression for a better explanation.

Comment: So how come this pattern posted by CommuSoft is working as well: `"/Identificador\s*:\s*(\w+)/"` ?

Comment: It's pretty much the same thing except his pattern takes into account the possible white spaces between and after "Idenftificador" and ":". That's what the multiple \s* are for.

Comment: Thanks, Kouga. You have helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First split the lines, then search for the one with "Identificator":

```
$initialString = "Status: Ativo
Identificador: F37CE5
Meio de Pagamento: Cartão de crédito
Data de contratação: 25/03/2015
Data de expiração: 25/03/2017";

$lines = explode("\n", $initialString);
foreach($lines as $line) {
  list($first, $second) = explode(":", $line);
  if (trim($first) == 'Identificator') {
    $important = $second;
    break;
  }
}
echo $important;
```

Comment: You don't know for sure it's the first line where the `identificador` is placed...

Comment: @CommuSoft alright, I changed it to search for the line

Comment: Thanks, man, but your code did not worked for me. $important is null.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is to make a substring having the correct start and then get the desired part:

```
$initialString = "Status: Ativo
Identificador: F37CE5
Meio de Pagamento: Cartão de crédito
Data de contratação: 25/03/2015
Data de expiração: 25/03/2017";

$substring = substr($initialString, strpos($initialString, "Identificador:") + 14);
$substring = substr($substring, 0, strpos($substring, "\n"));
```

Comment: Because the length of "Identificador:" is of 14 characters, the offset we need to add to the position of the string where "Identificador:" starts.

Comment: I see. But the problem with your code is that I cannot be sure that `Identificador: F37CE5` is always going to be alone in its line.

Comment: You did not specify that in your question

Answer (score 0):

if the string is always the same length you could do this

```
echo substr($important, 0, 6);
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael, but I cannot assume that.

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers suggest explode and splitting lines, this is generally really slow. You should use `strpos` and loop through the results.

In my tests (looped 10,000 times) it took my code only `0.249` seconds on a very large test string. Under the same conditions the other code posted on this page took `0.811` seconds to do the same task.

```
<?php
   $pos = 0;
   while(($pos = strpos($input,"Identificador:",$pos)) !== false) {
      $end = strpos($input,"\n",$pos);
      if($end) {
         $line = substr($input,$pos,$end-$pos);
         $parts = explode(':',$line);
         echo $parts[1]."\n";
         $pos = $end;
      }else{
         $pos++;
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, David. But your code seems too complicated for me. I know preg_match it's slower, but this is a task that will be performed from time to time only. Maybe once a day. And BTW, your code produce: `F37CE5
 37`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to capture the group:

```
preg_match("/Identificador\s*:\s*(\w+)/",$initialString,$matches);
```

the result is then stored in `$matches[1]`, or the array is empty if no match is found.

Comment: Thanks, man. I think Kouga posted the same code, but complete.